# unit testing of defined class using doctests

Tags: unit-testing, doctest

i wrote a docstring for doctests and i also wrote function correctly .
But when i run this on hacker rank then it shows Runtime error

I tried using docstring

```
class Circle():

    def __init__(self, radius):
        # Define the doctests for __init__ method below
    """
    >>>c1=Circle(2.5)
    >>>c1.radius()
    2.5
    """
         self.radius = radius

    def area(self):
    # Define the doctests for area method below
    """
    >>>c1 = Circle(2.5)
    >>>c1.area()
    19.63
    """
    # Define the area functionality below
        return round(math.pi*(self.radius**2),2)



    def circumference(self):
    # Define the doctests for circumference method below
    """
    >>>c1=Circle(2.5)
    >>>c1.circumference()
    15.71
    """
    # Define the circumference functionality below
        return round(2*math.pi*self.radius)
```

Runtime error

Comment: please provide the solution as soon as possible

Comment: Doesn't it violate hacker rank code of conduct?

Answer (score 0):

Your code (at least the way you presented it here) is not indented correctly, and that is crucial for Python. That is the most obvious explanation of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to keep space between '>>>' and c1. 
and also check that radius is variable so jsut use c1.radius.

class Circle():

```
def __init__(self, radius):
# Define the doctests for __init__ method below
"""
>>>c1=Circle(2.5)
>>>c1.radius
2.5
"""
self.radius = radius

def area(self):
# Define the doctests for area method below
"""
>>>c1 = Circle(2.5)
>>>c1.area()
19.63
"""
# Define the area functionality below
return round(math.pi*(self.radius**2),2)



def circumference(self):
# Define the doctests for circumference method below
"""
>>>c1=Circle(2.5)
>>>c1.circumference()
15.71
"""
# Define the circumference functionality below
return round(2*math.pi*self.radius,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import inspect
import doctest
import re
import math

# Define the class 'Circle' and its methods with proper doctests:
class Circle:
    
    def __init__(self, radius):
        # Define doctests for __init__ method:
        """
        >>> c1 = Circle(2.5)
        >>> c1.radius
        2.5
        """
        self.radius = radius
        
    def area(self):
        # Define doctests for area method:
        """
        >>> c1 = Circle(2.5)
        >>> c1.area()
        19.63
        """
        # Define area functionality:
        y=math.pi*(self.radius**2)
        return round(y,2)
        
        
    def circumference(self):
        # Define doctests for circumference method:
        """
        >>> c1 = Circle(2.5)
        >>> c1.circumference()
        15.71
        """
        # Define circumference functionality:
        x=math.pi*2*self.radius
        return round(x,2)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
    
    c2 = Circle(2.5)
    doc1 = inspect.getdoc(c2.__init__)
    doc2 = inspect.getdoc(c2.area)
    doc3 = inspect.getdoc(c2.circumference)
    
    class_count = len(re.findall(r'Circle', doc1))
    func1_count = len(re.findall(r'c1.radius', doc1))
    func1_val = len(re.findall(r'2.5', doc1))
    
    print(str(class_count), str(func1_count), str(func1_val))
    
    class_count = len(re.findall(r'Circle', doc2))
    func1_count = len(re.findall(r'c1.area', doc2))
    func1_val = len(re.findall(r'19.63', doc2)) 
                      
    print(str(class_count), str(func1_count), str(func1_val))
                      
    class_count = len(re.findall(r'Circle', doc3))
    func1_count = len(re.findall(r'c1.circumference', doc3))
    func1_val = len(re.findall(r'15.71', doc3)) 
                      
    print(str(class_count), str(func1_count), str(func1_val))
```